# Transition State search

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, transition-state-theory

I've been trying to find a  transition state for the reaction of Pd + F2 with no luck. Has anyone ever tried a similar reaction, have they managed to get the TS? The reaction proceeds from the reactants to a linear reactant complex forming a stable PdF2 product (104.4-degree angle).

Comment: Reaction of fluorine and metallic palladium produces [palladium(II,IV) fluoride, $\ce{Pd[PdF6]}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium(II,IV)_fluoride) which can further be fluorinated to form [palladium tetrafluoride, $\ce{PdF4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium_tetrafluoride)

Comment: What search algorithms have you tried?

Comment: @jezzo I have started with a linear transit search and found the maximum then ran a TS reaction coordinate, which does not converge.